# How to create PGP Public and Private keys from AsymmetricCipherKeyPair?

Tags: java, android, cryptography, openpgp

My goal is to genrate armoer eliptical curve (ECC) public and private key. So I have implemented the AsymmetricCipherKeyPair, now I have to convert it to OpenPGP Key so pass it for the KeyRingGenrator.

```
X9ECParameters parms = ECNamedCurveTable.getByOID(new ASN1ObjectIdentifier("curve25519"));
      ECParameterSpec domainparams =  EC5Util.convertToSpec(parms);

        ECDomainParameters domainParams = EC5Util.getDomainParameters(null,domainparams);


        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        ECKeyGenerationParameters keyParams = new ECKeyGenerationParameters(domainParams, secureRandom);

        ECKeyPairGenerator generator = new ECKeyPairGenerator();
        generator.init(keyParams);
        AsymmetricCipherKeyPair keyPair = generator.generateKeyPair();
```

After generation of the keyPair, I have to convert it into OpenPGP key pairs so that it could be passed in the following function.
`PGPKeyPair eccKeyPair = new PGPKeyPair("openPGPPublicKey", "openPGPPrivateKey");`

This function is further used for key ring generation.

```
PGPKeyRingGenerator    keyRingGen = new PGPKeyRingGenerator (PGPSignature.DEFAULT_CERTIFICATION,
                eccKeyPair ,
                "umaimaahmed1@gmail.com", null, null,
                null, new BcPGPContentSignerBuilder(PGPPublicKey.EC,
                HashAlgorithmTags.SHA256),
                new BcPBESecretKeyEncryptorBuilder(PGPEncryptedData.AES_256).build(passPhrase));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When looking at the API documentation I find:

> Deprecated. use `BcPGPKeyPair` or `JcaPGPKeyPair` as appropriate.

What about `BcPGPKeyPair`?

You're generating the key pair using Bouncy Castle's lightweight API after all.